# How to show captcha after few failed login attempts?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using RoR and its `has_secure_password` method. The User model has 'failed_login_attempts' field. If there are 5 failed attempts display the captcha. How can I do this? In the controller I check `user.failed_login_attempts <= 5` and if false redirect to login page with `flash['captcha'] = true` message. And in the view display captcha if `flash['captcha']`. Is it the right way or how should I check the need for captcha in the login page?

Comment: Use sessions to store how much failed login attempts are there

Comment: @ArpitSolanki, I don't think it's a good idea because the bruteforcer can start a new session every attempt

Comment: So use a backend cache like redis or just store it in the dB

Comment: @ArpitSolanki, so I do. The question is how to check if there is need for captcha in the view?

Comment: Simplest way, everytime they fail their login, add a strike to their user account in your db.  Just make a column to store this info.  Once they have two strikes make them use the captcha.  On every successful login, reset their strikes to zero.

Comment: @bkunzi01, yeah, but how to display captcha in the view? Is it good to use `flash`?

Comment: Just render a partial based upon if the user has strikes.  You could do it via ajax or page refresh depending on your needs.

Comment: if you're doing a redirect to the login page then it makes sense to use `flash`, which would be passed to the controller action that serves the login HTML page, but no further. At that point you could either reference `flash` from the view, or assign the value to an instance variable in the controller, but they're functionally the same here. Anyway, it sounds like this is already what you are doing, right?